# Adding webhook to project via CURLing Gitlab API

Tags: curl, webhooks, gitlab-api

I'm attempting to add a webhook to a project on Gitlab. See [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#add-project-hook)

I can GET current hooks from the project with the following command so I know I'm hitting gitlab successfully:

```
curl -k --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" <url>/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/hooks
```

However, I'm having issue creating a hook with a specific attribute. I can create a hook with the following command:

```
curl -k --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" <url>/api/v4/projects/<projectID>/hooks?url=<hookURL>
```

I want to set the "merge_requests_attribute" to "true". It is "false" by default. However, I'm unsure how to set this in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this so may as well post the answer:

Attributes on Gitlab can be manipulated with the `--data` tag.

So, in my case the command would include

`--data "merge_requests_events=true"`